# ¿Cómo añadir la función createdRow a mi codigo existente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y tengo este inconveniente ya que no se cómo integrar la función `createdRow` a mi código `JS`, me envía un error que el `ID` `tablaPersonas` ya esta siendo utilizado. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Para simplificar, lo que quiero hacer es darle color a las letras de una tabla determinada.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       tablaPersonas = $("#tablaPersonas").DataTable({
           "columnDefs":[{
            "targets": -1,
            "data":null,
            "defaultContent": "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary btnEditar'>Editar</button><button class='btn btn-danger btnBorrar'>Borrar</button></div></div>"  
           }],



        //Para cambiar el lenguaje a español
    "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "Columnvisibility": "DES",
            "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sSearch": "REALIZAR BÚSQUEDA:",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primero",
                "sLast":"Último",
                "sNext":"Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
             },
             "sProcessing":"Procesando...",


       });
})

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tablaPersonas').DataTable( {
        createdRow: function ( row, data, index ) {
            if ( data[1] > 1 ) {
                $('td', row).eq(1).addClass('highlight');

            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Porque no intentas hacerlo todo en una misma definicion?

Comment: es lo que quiero, pero me bota error, y mi pregunta es como añadir a la misma funcion, si sabes lo agradeceria.